# Apache AllowOverride equivalent in Lighttpd

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I've put a .htaccess file in my main directory of my lighttpd website like this:

```
url.rewrite-once = ( 
  "^/cat.php$" => "index.php"
)
```

And I have enabled mod_rewrite and mod_redirect in my lighttpd.conf and restarted lighttpd server.

But unfortunately when i type mydomain/cat.php i got error page 404.

I've found that in Apache there is necessery to write:

```
<Directory />
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

In config file. But I can not find equivalent of this setting for Lighttpd. What is this?

Comment: I think you picked the wrong alternaware.

Comment: @NSD why do you possibly think that?

Comment: @NSD If I would like to have neat docs i would use IIS but i don't. So when I don't find answer on any forum, google or in mod_rewrite part of docs I simply ask it here. Who in name of gods could discover that answer to very basic question for all apache refugees will be in other part of docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lighttpd doen't support .htaccess files - http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Do-you-support-htaccess-files

Answer (score 1):

Its true that Lighttpd doesn't support .htaccess files, you will have to add this to the lighttpd.conf file.

For example

```
$HTTP["host"] == "www.example.com" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/example.com/wwwroot/"
    url.rewrite-once = ( 
        "^/cat.php$" => "index.php"
    )
}
```

Lighttpd is a light weight server so it doesn't have all of the kitchen sink like feature of apache. That said you can do most of what you can do in apache just in a different way.